# Getting " Cannot find the file in the specified path sample.vbs" in windows XP while executing vbscript

Tags: vbscript, windows-runtime, linker-errors

Tried of executing Vbscript file but received the following error " Cannot able to find the file in specified path " I cannot able to run any of the vbs files which are running perfect in windows 7..

Is there is any workaround for this

Comment: Can you post your vbscript code and explain more your issue ?

Comment: The error what I am getting is "windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file . you may not have the appropriate permissions to access item ".         The code inside my file "C:\desktop\hello.vbs" consists of "MsgBox "Hello World"

Comment: Try reassociating the `VBS` extension with the `wscript.exe` executable. That will fix a file association issue (if there is one) as well as ensure that `wscript.exe` still exists!

Comment: Wscript.exe is there and I can able to see in open with options.. Reassociation vbs extension ?? I can't get that

Comment: Hold [Shift], right-click on a VBS file, hover over `"Open With..."`, select `"Choose default program..."`, then browse to `wscript.exe` and make sure to check the box to "Always use the selected program...".